# poential issue with the sql in my code, resulting in foreign key error

Tags: foreign-keys

I am trying to link my tables together so that the COURSE table will connect to the last table I am making. Not Sure how to fix the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (
Student_ID int not null,
Student_Name VARCHAR(25) not null,
Student_Gender CHAR(1) null,
Student_DOB DATE not null 
CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS Primary Key (Student_ID));

CREATE TABLE COURSE (
COURSE_NO int not null,
COURSE_Name VARCHAR(20) not null,
Instructor_Name VARCHAR(20) not null,
Semester_No int not null,
Year CHAR(4) not null,
CONSTRAINT PK_Courses PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_NO));

CREATE TABLE STUDENT_CLASS (
Student_ID int REFERENCES STUDENTS(Student_ID),
COURSE_NO int not null,
Semester_No int not null, 
Year CHAR(4) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Student_ID, COURSE_NO),
FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year) 
REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year));
```

Comment: What error? What issue? What does "connect to" mean? (Use technical terms, correctly.) Please read & act on [mcve]. Also [ask] and [help], and google 'stackexchange homework'. And your error message sans your table names. And read the official documentation re FKs. And this is a faq. (Could this possibly the first question about this? No.)

Answer (score 0):

If your `STUDENT_CLASS` `FOREIGN KEY (COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year) 
REFERENCES COURSE(COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year)` makes sense then the list `(COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year)` must be declared as `PK`(`PRIMARY KEY`) or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` in `COURSE`. Also given your names and schema, common sense suggests that a `PK` for `COURSE` should at least contain the columns in `(COURSE_NO, Semester_NO, Year)`. (If `COURSE_NO` were a `PK` then there could be at most one row with a given course number in that table.) You haven't told us enough to determine how to resolve the inconsistency, but it seems likely that you want that change in `PK`.